# Adding number of duplicates to a table

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to add the number of potential duplicates as a column to a table. Therefore I need to count the amount of persons that have the same attributes (first_name, last_name, birthyear) and count them like potential duplicates.

I can output the amount of potential duplicates by grouping them like this:

```
select first_name, last_name, birthyear, COUNT(*) -1 as duplicates
from people
group by first_name, last_name, birthyear
having birthyear is not null;
```

If the birthyear information is missing, then it won't count as an duplicate.

**But how could I add the resulting 'duplicates' column to the source table 'people' ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your query as a derived table (a subquery in the `FROM` clause) in the update command:

```
alter table people add duplicates int;

update people p
set duplicates = s.duplicates
from (
    select first_name, last_name, birthyear, count(*) -1 as duplicates
    from people
    where birthyear is not null
    group by first_name, last_name, birthyear
    ) s
where s.first_name = p.first_name
and s.last_name = p.last_name
and s.birthyear = p.birthyear;
```